# Pre microscope lens or Extension tubes , any difference

Tags: macro

I am currently using a 200mm F4 lens before my 5x microscope at the end, is this any different than using extension tubes instead of the 200mm lens to eliminate dust ?

Comment: Please clarify your setup.  Are you using the "microscope" to make photographs?  Or does "microscope" here mean something different from an instrument you look through with your eye?  Also, welcome to Photography Stack Exchange!  Please take our [tour] and read the [FAQ].  Your question is in danger of being closed because either a) it may not be a photography question or b) it's unclear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't clear this is about photography as opposed to microscopy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference, and it depends on the type of microscope objective being used.

If it is an infinity objective it must be mounted on an infinity tube; i.e. a lens focused at infinity... this is probably what you have.

If it is a finite objective it must be mounted at a specific fixed distance from the image sensor; i.e. an extension tube of specific length.